# Why does my 13" MacBook Pro have trouble running Adobe Bridge on a 27" Apple Monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, cinema-display

Configuration:
13" MacBook Pro 
2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
8GB RAM 
running Lion
Video: NVIDIA GeForce9400M 256MB. 
Apple 27" LED Cinema Display

It is a nice little computer but I am having trouble running Adobe CS5 Bridge. If I have even a few applications open, Bridge will flake out and I can't navigate to new folders or I get partial display.

If I close Bridge and disconnect the monitor I can open Bridge fine on the laptop. I then plug in the monitor and can continue to work.

This seems to be rather archaic, so I am wondering if there is something wrong with the video card or is there another reason I am having trouble running Bridge? What is the solution?

I would appreciate some expert insights.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you've run AAM to update all components to latest:

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/OOBE/PDApp/core/Adobe Application Manager.app
```

What happens when you set your displays to mirror (command-F1), launch Bridge, then revert back to extended?

Comment: Hi da4. Bridge and all other apps are current. I even tried downloading the trial version of Photoshop CS5.1 with Bridge 5.1 I get the same results there.